# Installing Qt 5.0 from source

Tags: windows, git, qt, qt5

I have recently used git to get the qt source code and I'm now slightly lost on what to do. I've been following the instructions on this page - http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git and I'm on windows 7.

I am at the 'Configuring and Building' stage now from the above link and have just finished the 'mingw32-make' step (about 2/3 down the page, just before the Building Qt Webkit step, which I won't be doing). So I left it running overnight and came back to it seemingly completed, as in there were no errors, failures, that I noticed on the command window output.

So my qt folder (installed at C:\Qt\qt5), looks something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyGW5.png

So here's a similar question asked on Stack Overflow that I've found, [How to install Qt on Windows after building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699311/how-to-install-qt-on-windows-after-building).

I've done step 4, which was to add QMAKE_INCDIR += "." to the qmake.conf file inside the qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++ folder. But now I need a bit of advice as to what to do next.

I already have Qt 5 installed from binary which I did months ago but before I delete that I would like to make sure this building from source plan is going to work right. So I also have Qt Creator and simply put, I would like to be able to open this and create a Qt project after I delete my binary installed version of Qt. How do I do this? I would have thought maybe put a path variable but I'm not sure where to put the path to. Do I need to change any settings inside Qt creator? Is the image above what I should be seeing, or is there some step I have still yet to take to finish build/install.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to setup your System Environment variables to your new QT bin directory and if your using Qt creator then point to this new QT setup in the project build settings, you'll basically point your Qt version with qmake and then make sure the tool chain contains the complier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jerry this worked fine.

I had already set the path variable but I hadn't made anything inside Qt Creator.

What I ended up doing was going into tools->options inside Qt Creator, going to the Build and Run option and adding my new version to the Kits tab and the Qt Versions tab. I then opened the projects tab and deleted my old kit, added the new version and was good to go!

Thanks again.

I can't up vote since that requires reputation so when (if) I get 15 rep I'll come back and up vote this answer.